# Why 4 regs to control a FSM? Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog

I'm studying an SDRAM controller (in Verilog), which uses 4 reg to control a FSM. I couldn't understand why they use 4 regs instead of 2 (state and next_state).

Here's the piece of code:

```
reg [STATE_SIZE-1:0] state_d, state_q = INIT;
reg [STATE_SIZE-1:0] next_state_d, next_state_q;
```

And here's the link to the controller: https://github.com/buffis/JammaGrabber/blob/602a47325acaad21340131ce41e283fc3e675a3b/FPGA/MojoJammaGrabber/src/sdram.v

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like it's tracking previous states after some delay -- see line 240.  I did *not* look hard, and I am *not* a digital logic expert, which is why this isn't an answer!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are `*_d` and `*_q` versions of each variable because the designer follows the practice of using two separate `always` blocks for his state machine.

The state machine requires timed waits at various stages of its operation, and instead of having a separate state for each one, he wrote just a single common `WAIT` state. The `next_state_*` variables tell the machine what to do when the `WAIT` is over.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to remember is that a Verilog "reg" doesn't always represent a register, whether or not it represents a register depends on how it is used.

The author of this code has implemented the state machine using two separate always blocks. The state machine logic is represented by a combinatorial always block while a sequential always block represents the registers. This structure means he needs Verilog regs to represent both the inputs "_d" and the outputs "_q" of his registers.

The advantage of this structure is that it allows the state machine to have combinatorial outputs. If you put the state machine logic in a sequential always block then all outputs from that logic must be registered.

Now in this particular case it looks like all outputs *are* registered, so he could have just put the logic in a sequential always block, but I suspect some people find it easier to stick to a consistent style even if said style is more verbose than necessary in most cases. Translating a single always block state machine to a two always block style because you found you did in-fact need a combinatorial output is no fun.

He has two state registers so he can have a single "wait" state that can lead to multiple different next states after the wait is over.

Two state registers, each with a separate Verilog "reg" for it's input and output makes four Verilog "reg"s.